# Ubuntu support for Unity3d

Tags: games

Does Ubuntu support Unity 3d? Which is the best speech API that is used in Ubuntu for Game development using unity3d

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 2 notable issues:

- 12.04 or higher and only 64-bit versions.
- A modern graphics card (Nvidia, AMD, or Intel)  and proprietary graphics drivers are required.

Installing using the official .deb will pull in all the necessary dependencies.

- [Source](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/)
- [Official .DEB download](http://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/unity-editor-5.1.0f3+2015082501_amd64.deb)  (amd64 only).
- Feedback for Unity3d + linux can be left on [this forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/linux-editor-support-feedback-experimental.93/).

---

> Which is the best speech API that is used in Ubuntu for Game development using unity3d

Impossible to answer since you do not quantify what you need for it to be considered as "best". All of them will have features and quirks. It is just how your demands line up with the features and the quirks and that is highly personal. Looks like google speech api works (not tried it though)  and that one is used on a lot of places. Might be a good 1st attempt.